# WCF Data Services and Breeze::throw new Error("Breeze does not yet support saving thru OData");

Tags: breeze

OData for WebAPI is rather ancient and doesn't support a lot of features WCF Data Services do.
I can't use WebAPI's OData support at all b/c of those too many limitations.

That makes breezeJS useless. 
So the question is why is it 100% tied to WebAPI ODATA and is not a separate 'adapter' in the first place?

Most of the worlds' oData services are similar to WCF Data Services and not to WebAPI sub-limited support.

1. I don't want to carry 125 KB of useless code (WebAPI support that is) in top of the DataJS library when targeting WCF Data Services
2. I can't even use Breeze if saving through WCF Data Services is not supported!
3. When we will really have full support for WCF Data Services like you did for WebAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question 2 there is a feature request for that at https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3349980-full-odata-crud-support

Please vote if this is important for you too! (I did)